# Testing QTP s Application Crash Recovery scenario

Tags: testing, automation, qtp

I need to VALIDATE the UFT(QTP) tool to use it in our Medical Automation testing projects. My Manual Test Lead has given a requirement that UFT must be able to recover from an Application Crash.

For this I have to use a sample application which is provided by UFT.
As of now everything is fine, as I can enable and create an Application Crash Recovery Scenario using Recovery Scenario Manager in UFT.

The problem is I have to prove them practically that UFT will recover from the application crash, for this, first I have to CRASH the sample application and then test UFT if it is able to recover from that crash.

So I have been googling about how to crash that wpf sample application provided by HP.

Please help me crashing the app.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: There is no "recover the app if the app crashes" feature in QTP. You sure can program your own. The recovery scenario feature is solely for detecting and handling unexpected states, and yes, this feature might be a good base for programming a "crashed AUT re-setter", but, as I said, you´ll have to program your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it sufficient to use Windows' [`taskkill`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) command?